# Set 802.1Q tagged port on VLAN1 on Dell PowerConnect switch

Tags: networking, dell, vlan, 802.1

I'm having big troubles when adding this Dell switch to my network.

Here we use several VLANs to segment traffic.  All switches (3com and DLink mostly) have configured the same VLANs, most ports are 'untagged' and belong to a single VLAN, except for the ports used to join together the switches (in a star topology), these ports belong to *all* VLANs and use 802.1Q tags.  So far, it works really well.

But on this new switch (a Dell PowerConnect 5448), the settings are very different (and confusing). I have configured the same VLANs, an the uplink ports are set in 'general' mode (supposed to be fully 802.1Q compliant), I can set the VLAN membership as 'T' on these ports for all VLANs except VLAN 1.  It always stay as 'U' on VLAN 1.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that there's no way around it, and that I shouldn't be using VLAN 1... can anybody elaborate why is it unadvised?  some switches only answer to administration commands on VLAN1, so if i can't appropriately tag it, i can't administer them from any point in the LAN...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLAN 1 on a Dell switch is a default system vlan.

Unless someone else knows a way around this (I personally don't and I've spent an eternity on this) VLAN 1 CAN NOT be routed or included in Layer 3 functions. I've given up on using that description and vlan number altogether.

You might be able to move "default" functionality to a vlan other than 1, then delete it, then re-add it as a user vlan, possibly with a reboot??? I've never had this work though. Then again I'm used to working on the "gold-plated" equipment.

Comment: This is excatly how I've done it -- define a new VLAN, define the management interface and default route on the new VLAN, then put a "router" interface on VID 1.  You can then route and manage through the interface on VID 1.

Answer (score 4):

Uhg, I hate those switches (well the whole power connect line really). I'm thinking back a bit because we pulled all but a few of those switches out of our infrastructure and don't use VLAN1 (Which is really bad practice btw)

So this is what I remember about those switches, and seems to be confirmed by the current config on one of my remaining 5224's:

The dell switches need a "native vlan" even on trunked ports. This VLAN *must* be untagged. I left it at VLAN 1 as we only use it as a parking vlan for shutdown ports on our switches. Our config looks like (sorry syntax might be slightly different on the newer models but this should get you started):

```
interface ethernet 1/7
 description XOVER to <core_switch> 3/3
 no negotiation
 switchport allowed vlan add 1 untagged
 switchport native vlan 1
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport allowed vlan add 1,3-10 tagged
```

what you would want to do is pick a VLAN you don't use and assign it as a native VLAN so that you config looks something like:

```
interface ethernet 1/7
 description XOVER to CORE 3/3
 no negotiation
 switchport allowed vlan add 666 untagged
 switchport native vlan 666
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport allowed vlan add 3-10, 666 tagged
```

You'll notice the native VLAN is both tagged and untagged - I'm pretty sure it ignores the "tagged" part of the configuration for the native vlan is ignored.

I hope that at least gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: +1 - Except that I don't hate the PowerConnect switches, that all jibes with my experience with them. They have a quirky configuration (and quirkly layer 3 functionality), but in general they've done what I want (and are *VASTLY* cheaper than Cisco's gold-plated comparable offerings).

Comment: great, it seems the 'trunk' mode is what i really want.  i managed to change the native vlan, but still doesn't let me add VLAN1 as untagged.  it complains that "vlan not created by user"

Comment: sorry, of course i meant "still doesn't let me add VLAN1 as tagged"

Comment: +1 content, also no hate for PowerConnect.

Answer (score 1):

I got a couple of R700 Ruckus AP's working with the following config.

```
interface ethernet 1/g5
negotiation 100f 1000f
description 'NA'
switchport mode general
switchport general pvid 20
switchport general allowed vlan add 20
switchport general allowed vlan add 99 tagged
lldp transmit-tlv port-desc sys-name sys-desc sys-cap
lldp transmit-mgmt
exit
```