# vlan switch port modes

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, access-point

I have a powerconnect 5548p switch and Linksys 4410N wireless access point.

I would like to host two SSIDs on the access point--one going to VLAN1 (default VLAN) and the other going to a separate VLAN (VLAN10).

On the switch port that the access point connects to--should it be trunk mode for VLAN1 and VLAN10, or general mode with VLAN1 untagged and VLAN10 tagged? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port connected to the AP should be a trunkport, meaning that it should tag all packets with their respective VLAN ids.

Comment: I ended up using the traditional trunk mode. I removed all the VLANs from the trunked port, added the two I wanted, and disabled the default (untagged) VLAN option.

On the access point, I enabled VLANing, assigned the management VLAN to the same VLAN where the office DHCP server is, and created two SSIDs and assigned each to its own VLAN.

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is correct... it should be a "general" port with VLAN1 untagged and VLAN10 as tagged.

Comment: What value does general mode add over a simple trunk with native vlan 1?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that "trunk" mode on a Dell switch only allows tagged traffic, whereas "general" is basically a trunk that also allows you to set the native vlan for the untagged traffic.

Comment: From what I've read in the switch's manual, "trunk" mode just passes packets along without adding or removing vlan tags. I wasn't sure about "general" mode since I hadn't encountered it before.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff, I still believe you can configure Vlan1 as untagged on a real trunk port, since it's the native vlan... see [Zypher's answer here](http://serverfault.com/questions/98307/set-802-1q-tagged-port-on-vlan1-on-dell-powerconnect-switch#link-post-222240)

Comment: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/network-switches/f/866/t/19335968.aspx